# Help. I accident sent ETH to the Contract

Tags: transactions

Total noob here.

Yesterday I attempted to transfer some ETH from Binance to my Trust Wallet. It says the transaction has been completed but I’ve not received the coins.

I believe I may have sent the coins to the contract address, is there any way I can confirm this, a way I can forward them to my wallet or are they gone/ stuck in the network?

I’ve attached pictures of the transaction…

Thank you. [image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to this address: [0x32639B7ee39cB8AFA309f1BBCE789F184b55B263](https://bscscan.com/address/0x32639B7ee39cB8AFA309f1BBCE789F184b55B263)
Then you can recover your money by interacting with this contract: [0x2170ed0880ac9a755fd29b2688956bd959f933f8](https://bscscan.com/token/0x2170ed0880ac9a755fd29b2688956bd959f933f8)
by going in "Contract" -> Write Contract

Comment: Thanks dude. 

Would you explain what I do once I’m in “Write”, I’m faced with numerous drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. I selected my wallet as ETH Coin and not ETH-ERC20.

Thanks for the help.